# Объясните почему при вводе параметров в фабричную функцию я получаю объект None

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Привет я написал так называемую фабричную функцию от которой я должен получить результат выражения 16*4, но вместо этого я получаю объект None

```
def func():
 x=4
 def func2(h):
  h*x
 return func2
f=func()(16)
print(f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ретурн забыл

```
def func():
 x=4
 def func2(h):
  return h*x
 return func2
f=func()(16)
print(f)
```